# Find duplicate word from a sentence using for loop (no inbuilt function)

Tags: java, for-loop, count, duplicates

As i am new to java i got a task to find duplicate word only and its count. i stuck in a place and i am unable to get the appropriate output. I can not use any collections and built in tool. i tried the below code. Need some help, Please help me out.

```
public class RepeatedWord 
  {
   public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          String sen = "hi hello hi good morning hello";
          String word[] = sen.split(" ");
          int count=0;
          for( int i=0;i<word.length;i++)
             {
                for( int j=0;i<word.length;j++)
                   {
                       if(word[i]==word[j])
                          {
                             count++;
                          }
                System.out.println("the word "+word[i]+" occured"+ count+" time");
                   }

             }

       }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions should not be "moving targets." Your original code used `==`, and you got an answer correctly telling you not to use `==`. It's not appropriate at that point to change the question to using `equals` instead. If your code actually has the `==`, then you have your answer. If there is a separate, further problem, that's a separate question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you marked it is duplicate.and you shared a link, i didnt find anything related to my question on that question.

Comment: Using `==` to compare strings is what's related. If you have a **different** bug in the code, revealed after fixing it, ask a question about that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes that was my silly mistake sorry for that. now after i changing it when i am trying to run code its showing only first element is duplicate not others. like i got 2 duplicates one *hi* and another *hello*

Comment: For the third time: Ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Compare String with `equals()` not with `==`

```
if(word[i].equals(word[j]))
```

`==` compares the refrence
`equals()` compares the value of that object.

Apart from that second loop should have `j<word.length`

Change code to

```
String sen = "hi hello hi good morning hello";
String word[] = sen.split(" ");
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {

        if (word[i].equals(word[j])) {
            count++;
        }

    }
    if(count>1)   //show only duplicate word
    System.out.println("the word " + word[i] + " occured " + count + " time");
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/bSWeVT)

Comment: yes i did but still not getting output properly.

Comment: the word hi occured1 time
the word hi occured1 time
the word hi occured2 time
the word hi occured2 time
the word hi occured2 time
the word hi occured2 time
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
 at RepeatedWord.main(RepeatedWord.java:13)

Comment: above out put i am getting

Comment: i tried the above code only its showing first elements count

Comment: @TTK you have problen in you second loop `for( int j=0;i<word.length;j++)` check carefully updated my code also check http://ideone.com/bSWeVT

Comment: yea i got it. but i am getting out put for each iteration. actually i want out put like below. *the word hello occured 2 time the word hi occured2 time* this two out put i want only

Comment: the duplicate word i want to print only with count

Comment: @TTK then just place if condition before print checking if count is greater than 1 check the link   http://ideone.com/bSWeVT

Comment: yea thanks. its showing the out put multiple time that the word hi occured 2 time the word hello occured 2 time can we print it only once not for repeated time. i think its printing multiple time for looping. can we ??